# Correct calculation of effect size after Friedman test in a skewed population

Tags: nonparametric, effect-size

I have some data that compares behaviour in four conditions (repeated measures)(I have several different behavioural variables and each behaviour gets analysed separately, and the behaviours are currently in % of time format). The behavioural variables are very non-normal, even after transformation. So I have run Friedman tests for the omnibus tests (friedman.test in R). For posthocs I have used friedman from the Agricolae package, but I would also like to report effect sizes. I am not sure which is the correct calculation to use because the data is not only non-normal, but also very positively skewed. I have tried the rFromWilcox function from Field but I am not sure it is the right one to use. Also I am getting r results such as -0.564NULL.
I am quite new to doing my own analysis, but keen to learn, so please don't be offended if I haven't phrased something quite right.

@Michael: I am trying to determine if certain behaviours occur more or less often under the different conditions, and where those differences are (nothing too deep). Two similar but different treatments are applied between condition one and two, and between three and four. I am predicting that there will be certain changes (some behaviours will increase and some will decrease) between all conditions but particularly between one and two, and three and four. My posthocs test between all pair combinations and I have used a Bonferroni correction. I was planning on reporting the summary stats, for each condition for each behaviour, the test statistic and p value, and posthoc results where Friedman is significant, and effect sizes on those posthocs.

Comment: What hypotheses and "effects" are you interested in? How are you presenting your data descriptively (what numbers and figures do you intend to show)?